# How to access a view in a laravel module with routes?

Tags: laravel

I'm currently working on my homework for school which i've read about Laravel modules and i'm currently working with this `https://nwidart.com/laravel-modules` package.

I've managed to create modules, migrations and models. now i want to access a module via a simple link from route. like this:

```
    <a href="{{ route('crm.index') }}">CRM</a>
```

I've created 3 modules with core,crm and sell names. which base on information from internet, I've understand that i can access them with `localhost/crm or sell or core`. now how i can fix my problem?

I've also tried `{{ route('core::index') }}`. Thanks

Update 1: Views in every module are like this: `Resources\views\index.blade.php` if u look at above link u will see a example of what i've said.

Update 2: routes: Every module have 1 route when i create module with package.

Laravel root module `routes\web` :

```
Route::get('/', function () {
  return view('welcome');
});
```

and CRM route module `Modules\CRM\routes\web\` and rest are just like below with different names :

```
Route::prefix('core')->group(function() {
  Route::get('/', 'CoreController@index');
});
```

Comment: show the routes in `routes/web.php`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ i've added, it's in update 2.

Comment: ok, try with `<a href="{{ url('core') }}">CRM</a>` instead of `{{ route('crm.index') }}` in the <a>

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ it's worked, i've also tried with normal links and it's also worked, but how about routes? i've saw in some github projects they using `route` to reach it, and how about queries? if i try to use it to get data and show it in page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`route()`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#method-route) helper is for named routes. You can use [`url()`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#method-url) helper to match a uri, or you have to add a name to your route, like:

```
Route::prefix('core')->group(function() {
  Route::get('/', 'CoreController@index')->name('core.index');
});
```

and then you can

```
<a href="{{ route('core.index') }}">CRM</a>
```

Comment: aha, i knew about naming, but since the process of creating module was simple and base of my searches they didn't changed any thing, i thought it's just simple like how i i've accessed the module. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I use like this to address view page in module controller:

```
return view("module::pages.main");
```

module is your module name.

Answer (score 1):

try to set name for your route

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#named-routes

```
Route::prefix('core')->group(function() {
  Route::get('/', 'CoreController@index')->name('crm.index');
});
```

and then this should work

```
<a href="{{ route('crm.index') }}">CRM</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version 6 i change the view resource config and read from modules folder like this :

```
    'paths' => [
    base_path('Modules/Duet/Resources/views'),
    base_path('Modules/anotherModule/Resources/views'),
],
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the name for your route in your module
e.g:

```
    Route::get('/yourRoute', function(){
         return ('yourView');
    })->name('yourname');
```

your views are access to the name of your route.